# Convert date into string using full format

Tags: javascript, date

Is there a simple way to convert a :

`new Date()`

into a string with the full format like this :

`"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ"`

Comment: Its not exactly a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

This is `zulu` time as denoted by "Z" in the last.